# How do I check if a string has only alphanumeric characters in guava?

Tags: java, guava

Actually, I would like to check if it has only alphanumeric plus these: .-_ [space]

If using an external library I would like to use Guava since it's already included in my project...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regexp-free and somewhat more readable (?) solution could be using Guava's [`CharMatcher`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) class:

```
boolean matched = CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT.or(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE)
    .or(CharMatcher.anyOf("_.-")).matchesAllOf(yourString);
```

Maybe ASCII chars are OK for your use case? If so, use:

```
boolean matched = CharMatcher.ASCII.matchesAllOf(yourString);
```

See [wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#CharMatcher) for examples and description.

Also, you may want to extract your matcher to constant and precompute it:

```
private static final CharMatcher CHAR_MATCHER = CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT
    .or(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE)
    .or(CharMatcher.anyOf("_.-"))
    .precomputed();
```

What's more interesting, if you read `CharMatcher`'s documentation you may find that ["digit"](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#JAVA_DIGIT), ["letter"](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#JAVA_LETTER) and ["whitespace"](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#WHITESPACE) in Java are quite ambigious terms:

> Determines whether a character is a digit according to Java's definition. If you only care to match ASCII digits, you can use `inRange('0', '9')`.

or

> Determines whether a character is a letter according to Java's definition. If you only care to match letters of the Latin alphabet, you can use `inRange('a', 'z').or(inRange('A', 'Z'))`.

so you may want use explicit char ranges:

```
private static final CharMatcher CHAR_MATCHER_ASCII = 
    CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9')
        .or(CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z'))
        .or(CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z'))
        .or(CharMatcher.anyOf(" _.-")) // note space here
        .precomputed();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need any library. You can do it with regex with plain Java.

Regex: `([A-Za-z0-9\-\_\. ]+)`

```
myStr.matches("([A-Za-z0-9\-\_\. ]+)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need guava. Just do String#matches with a suitable [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

i..e

```
str.matches("[1-9a-zA-Z.\\-_ ]*");
```

Answer (score 0):

[:alnum:] - Alphanumeric characters for Apache Regular Expression API